# List all git commits containing at least one file with .txt file extension

Tags: git, windows-7, text-files, commit, tortoisegit

I am under windows 7 with TortoiseGit. I have a local git repository with several hundred commits and I would like to find all commits having at least one file ending in `.txt`.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: with tortoisegit I don't know! but with a console you can use `git --log --oneline -- "*.txt"`. The `--oneline`-option gives you a overview of all commits.

Comment: @silvio it worked, but I had to remove the -- before log, it seems to be: git log --oneline -- "*txt" If you create a solution, I'll approve it...

Comment: you are right. `log` not `--log`. Thx for your hint :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tortoisegit I don't know!

But with a console you can use `git log --oneline -- "*.txt"`. The `--oneline`-option gives you a overview of all commits.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the `Show log` and in the search bar and type `.txt`.